# How to get the file extension from a url?

Tags: ruby

New to ruby, how would I get the file extension from a url like:

```
http://www.example.com/asdf123.gif
```

Also, how would I format this string, in c# I would do:

```
string.format("http://www.example.com/{0}.{1}", filename, extension);
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using the URI or Addressable/URI libraries. While you can directly inject values into the URL using formatting, the libraries offer lots of nice features for splitting the URL into its components, rebuilding it, and making sure the url is structured correctly.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use [File.extname](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M002543)

```
File.extname("test.rb")         #=> ".rb"
File.extname("a/b/d/test.rb")   #=> ".rb"
File.extname("test")            #=> ""
File.extname(".profile")        #=> ""
```

To format the string

```
"http://www.example.com/%s.%s" % [filename, extension]
```

Comment: so if the return value is "", how would I check for that in a if statement?   if extesion == ""     ?

Comment: It appears `File.extname` will not strip off a query string.  So if your url is `http://www.example.com/download.mp3?hello=world` then it will return `.mp3?hello=world`.  Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: This works well if there isn't a query string. I recommend Orlando's answer if there could be one.

Answer (score 33):

This works for files with query string

```
file = 'http://recyclewearfashion.com/stylesheets/page_css/page_css_4f308c6b1c83bb62e600001d.css?1343074150'
File.extname(URI.parse(file).path) # => '.css'
```

also returns "" if file has no extension

Comment: but this will fail for: "http://recyclewearfashion.com", or, at the least, gives wrong answer

Comment: @Itzik984 that has an invalid protocol (missing http(s)), so is not a valid URI

Comment: this will fail for "http :// recyclewearfashion.com" as well :)

Comment: @Itzik984 these are not valid URIs, you should sanitize your input before using this code.

Answer (score 6):

```
url = 'http://www.example.com/asdf123.gif'
extension = url.split('.').last
```

Will get you the extension for a URL(in the most simple manner possible). Now, for output formatting:

```
printf "http://www.example.com/%s.%s", filename, extension
```

Comment: Neither solution deals with query parameters, so you might need to add URI.parse For the second part, "http://www.example.com/#{filename}.#{extension}" will do

Comment: And more beautifully `url.split('.').last` and `"http://www.example.com/%s.%s" % [filename, extension]`.

Comment: @MarkThomas: Then it wouldn't have an extension. The point isn't to account for every scenario, it's to give a basic idea of how to do things without throwing regex, etc. at a newbie.

Comment: So you define the point, Rafe.  How do you know he won't learn and love regex?  How do you know the point is not to let him be exposed to different ways to do one thing?  You have to define what the point is?

Comment: @Rafe, *my* point was your solution would give it an incorrect extension of "com/dir", certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an ancient question, but here's another vote for using [Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable). You can use the `.extname` method, which works as desired even with a query string:

```
 Addressable::URI.parse('http://www.example.com/asdf123.gif').extname # => ".gif"
 Addressable::URI.parse('http://www.example.com/asdf123.gif?foo').extname # => ".gif"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use Ruby's [URI class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html) like this to get the fragment of the URI (i.e. the relative path of the file) and split it at the last occurrence of a dot (this will also work if the URL contains a query part):

```
require 'uri'
your_url = 'http://www.example.com/asdf123.gif'
fragment = URI.split(your_url)[5]

extension = fragment.match(/\.([\w+-]+)$/)
```

Comment: Again, why are regular expressions necessary when he can just call to `string.split()`?

Comment: Removed the RegExp while you were commenting ;)

Comment: @Jakub: Using the `URI::split` method should also take care of those cases.

irb(main):020:0> URI.split('http://www.example.org/test.php?myparam=1234.435.24')[5].split('.')[-1]
=> "php"

Comment: Oh, yes of course, that was really a comment promoting this answer. So even if it seems a bit more complex then the one-liners it is also much more robust.

Comment: Before you edited, it was correct. Now it will fail on a URL like "http://www.example.com/news.release/"

Comment: Hm, that's right.. Overlooked that case indeed, so I'm gonna revert to using the RE.

Comment: Be aware that '`fragment`' is a proper part of a URL: it's the part following `#` at the end, specifying a location in the page. `http://www.example.com/asdf123.gif#foo` has `#foo` as its fragment. Calling the filename a fragment is confusing when dealing with URLs.