# Rails - Split url to get the last part of it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, split, breadcrumbs

I am using breadcrumbs_on_rails gem. To make it work nicely I need to set the names of the links. To get them I want to get the last part of the url but I have problem with spliting of the string.

in the class:

```
x = :page_path
add_breadcrumb  x, :page_path
```

Result:

```
/pages/offer.html
```

But when I make:

```
x = :page_path
add_breadcrumb  x.to_s.split('/'), :page_path
```

I get:

```
["page_path"]
```

Can somebody give ma a hint what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what do the `add_breadcrumb` function. But `x.to_s.split('/')` = `"page_path"` so your second line is like `add_breadcrumb  'page_path', :page_path`

Comment: "add_breadcrumb  <something>, :page_path" means that breadcrumb path will be obtained by calling function page_path, so x = :page_path looks weird. What do you really want to do?

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113598/how-to-get-the-file-extension-from-a-url